# How to find position in outer coordinates of a point inside a rotated rectangle?

Tags: trigonometry

I have a feeling this has a simple solution however it eludes me. It's a simplified version of a real problem. Any tips or pointers are appreciated.

[image]

Given a point inside a rectangle where you know the position of the point relative to the rectangle boundary (`b, a` in the image). When the rectangle is rotated $\pi/4$ so it touches the axis, what is the coordinates of the point in the outer coordinates.

The width and height of the internal rectangle are also known.

Comment: For both segments $a$ and $b$, it is easy to find the lengths of their projections onto the horizontal and vertical axes.

Comment: Ooh, so you can do C + project(b) - project(a) = x, and C + project(a) - project(b) = y, thanks.

Comment: For $y$, the length $c$ is not related. $y = a\cos\frac\pi4 + b\sin\frac\pi4$. @Annan

Answer (score 1):

In general, the black rectangle was transformed by a translation after rotation.

First, the red dot has a coordinate $\begin{bmatrix}b\\a\end{bmatrix}$.

The black rectangle is rotated anticlockwise by $\theta = \frac\pi4$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}b\\a\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}b\cos\theta-a\sin\theta\\b\sin\theta+a\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$$

Then the rotated black rectangle is translated right by $\begin{bmatrix}c\\0\end{bmatrix}$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}c\\0\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}c+b\cos\theta-a\sin\theta\\b\sin\theta+a\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$$